# How to link up js variable with html form and send to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have asked already similar question but I couldn't find good solution.
I have got a variable in js called 'lat', which are numbers(lattitude).
I would like to connect this variable with form, which I have on my site, 
and send it with other information inserting by users, to php file when clicking submit button in the end of the form.

```
<form action="address.php" method="post" class = "form1">

<--some input fields-->



<textarea id = "jj" name="comentary" cols="32" rows="12" wrap="virtual"></textarea></p>
<p class ="p2"><input type ="submit"  id = "ff" value="Send"></p>

</form>
```

My js script is in head tag, where in function I obtain "lat" from user choice on map.

```
var lat =  input.lat();
```

I have tried with lots of scripts to solve it, including Ajax etc.
 but none of them was worked. Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a hidden input to your form to store the lat variable value:

```
<form action="address.php" method="post" class = "form1">
    <input type='hidden' id='latValue'>
    <--some input fields-->



    <textarea id = "jj" name="comentary" cols="32" rows="12" wrap="virtual"></textarea>    </p>
    <p class ="p2"><input type ="submit"  id = "ff" value="Send"></p>

</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var lat = input.lat();

$("#latValue").val(lat);
```

Because it is an input on the form, it will automatically get sent up with the form post.

Comment: I was typing out the same answer, so I will upvote yours.  I would also make it clear that the OP should make sure to do the jQuery update to the hidden input whenever the user makes a selection from the map.

Comment: Also, your hidden input needs a `name` attribute.

Comment: It should work but it doesn't. I dont know why I still got empty string in place where I display variable in php. My php file receives lat with this line now: $lat = $_POST['latValue']; ,is it correct ?

Comment: Yees, I should have add name field, my 3-day issue is solved. Thanks a lot guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the value static? You could add a hidden element to the form containing the value of lat.
For instance in jQuery:

```
var latElement = $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden");
latElement.val(lat);
$(".form1").prepend(latElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure javaScript,

```
var lat = input.lat();

document.getElementById("latValue").value = lat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this hidden field inside your form tag:

```
<input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value="">
```

Then `$('#lat').val(lat);` for jQuery or `document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;` if you're just using JavaScript.

Then when the form is submitted you will have the value of the "lat" field as form variable.